# List of class objects does not work

Tags: python, list, pyqt4

I wrote a method where i use a global variable called `channelcount`and two lists called `listofchannels_1` and `listofchannels_2` .When i press a combination of keys (ctrl+shift+c), a class object called `ViewWidget`(which is a matplotlib figure) is shown in my `QMainWindow`. It goes like this up to 3 times. You can see this in this image:

[image]

I want to add this class object to `listofchannels_1` and at the same time add in `listofchannels_2` a name for the object such as: "Channel 1, Channel 2 and Channel 3".

This is the method i wrote (addChannel):

```
channel count = 1
listofchannels_1 = []           #These are the global variables
listofchannels_2 = []

Class Window (QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
  #A lots of stuff in here


  def addChannel(self):
    global channelCount, listofchannels_1, listofchannels_2
    graphic = ViewWidget() #This is the matplotlib figure (the class object)

    if channelCount <= 3: 
        self.splitter.addWidget(graphic)
        channelCount += 1
        return channelCount

        for i in listofchannels_1:
            listofchannels_1.append(graphic(i))
            for channel in listofchannels_2:
                channel_name[i] = "Channel" + str(channelCount)
                print channel_name[i]
```

I also want to print both lists every time an item is added, so i can check if an item was created in each list.

When i build this, it does not print anything, and i do not know if the items are added to the lists as i want.

I am new in python and sometimes i do not know if i wrote correctly the code. What am i doing wrong? Is there another way to not use these empty lists as globals? In this way i can use these lists later, if i need to.

## ---------- EDIT----------

I modified the method `addchannel` in the `Window`class like this:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    self.addChannel()
    self.channelCount = 1
    self.listofchannels_1 = []
    self.listofchannels_2 = []

  def addChannel(self):
    graphic = ViewWidget()
    if self.channelCount <= 3:
      self.splitter.addWidget(graphic)
      channelCount += 1
      self.listofchannels_1.append(graphic(i))
      for i in self.listofchannels_1:
            channel_name[i] = "Channel " + str(self.channelCount)
            self.listofchannels_2.append(channel_name[i])
            print channel_name[i]
    return self.channelCount
```

Now, i am getting an error saying: "Window" object has no attribute `channelCount`. I wrote something wrong?

How can i know if i am adding `graphic(i)`into `listofchannels_1`?

## -------- EDIT 2 ------------

It finally works. This is the final code:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
  channelCount = 0
  listofchannels_1 = []
  listofchannels_2 = []
  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def addChannel(self):
    graphic = ViewWidget() 
    if Window.channelCount <= 2: #Sólo agregaremos hasta 3 canales
        self.splitter.addWidget(graphic)
        Window.channelCount += 1
        Window.listofchannels_1.append(graphic)
        channel_name = "Channel " + str(Window.channelCount)
        Window.listofchannels_2.append(channel_name)
        print channel_name
        print Window.listofchannels_1
        print Window.listofchannels_2
    return Window.channelCount
```

I put the variable `channelCount`and the lists before the **init** method to use them not as global, but as instance variables. This is something that i learned while i was trying to solve mi problem.

The `print`lines are just to see if there were elements in the lists and if they were the correct elements. So with the `channelCount` variable; i wanted to see if it was changing its value.

Comment: You haven't said what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, i have already edit it.

Comment: Does python have static class variables?

Comment: You never add anything to listofchannels_2, so the inner for loop will never be executed.

Comment: Is list of channels a list of integers? if not, you'd never be able to look up `channel_name[i]`

Comment: The listofchannel_2 are integers, the listofchannel_1 is for class object. Are these ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of things that are wrong.

Firstly, the "return" statement will end the function and return the value. Having a return statement half way through your function means that the rest of the function will never execute. Put it at the end of the function if you want to return something once it's finished.

In the below block, you haven't actually got a variable called `channel_name` that I can see, you'll have to create it before you can start.

```
    for i in listofchannels_1:
        listofchannels_1.append(graphic(i))
        for channel in listofchannels_2:
            channel_name[i] = "Channel" + str(channelCount)
            print channel_name[i]
```

If you channels lists are only every used in the window class, it may be worth making them a members of the class rather than global. You set and access them using self.variableName, as in:

```
Class Window (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.channelCount = 1
        self.listofchannels_1 = []          
        self.listofchannels_2 = []

    def printChannelNames(self):
        for channel in self.listofchannels_2:
            print channel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am i not creating the variable `channel_name`in the way that i wrote it? What i wanted to do is: "For each element in listofchannels_1,  create a variable called channel_name and add it to listofchannels_2". I miss the append part now that i look again.

Comment: Exactly, what you would want is either to create a list of a certain length with dummy values (if you already know the length) that you can replace using channel_name[i] (e.g. `channel_name = ["" for x in range(3)]` creates a list of 3 empty strings) or create it empty like you've done, and use append instead. The latter is a lot more flexible but also a little more risky since the size of the list changes throughout

Comment: I modified the code as you can see in above. I did what you adviced me, and i now i have the variables inside the class (not globals anymore), the `return` statement at the end,  and "for each item `graphic`i add to `listofchannels_1`, a variable `channel_name[i]` is created and added to `listofchannels_2`. But now i´m getting an Error saying that there is no variable `channelCount`. Thank you for your answers, you are helping me a lot.

Comment: You're wecome, glad to be helpful. I think I can see a bit better what you are trying to do. You actually want channel list to be regular variable, and not a list. You've written something halfway. Doing channel_name[i] tells python to look for the ith elemnt of channel_name, which doesnt exist yet. What you want is simply `channel_name = "Channel " + str(self.channelCount)` and then `self.listofchannels_2.append(channel_name)` (essentially what you had just without any i's)

Comment: or even simpler, append it directly: `self.listofchannels_2.append("Channel " + str(self.channelCount))`

Comment: I've had another look at your code and I see that you are probably going to fall into the trap that `append()` poses. Each time the addChannel() function is called, it will append all the existing channel names to the second list. Meaning you will end up with an output looking like ["1", "1", "2, "1", "2", "3"]. Your best bet is to scrap the for loop entirely and simply do `self.listofchannels_2.append("Channel " + str(self.channelCount))` and a `print self.listofchannels_2` instead

Comment: Thank you @user3088440 for all your help. Indeed, i fall in the trap of append(). But i solved it as you can see above, in the changes i have made in the code.

Comment: Yeah that all looks right. You can use `self.variable` as opposed to `Window.variable` btw, although Id imagine that the result is the same anyway